# Event distinction by key with Return and Intro in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-core, keyboard

Using Sap Business One I realised they make a distinction between intro key (numeric keyboard) and enter/return key. Events raised are differents depending on which one I press. That made me think I could control both events separately.

In C# I can set a keydown event using this method:

```
static void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // my code here
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Only problem is that I have the very same result no matter which key I press. There are two values, Enter and Return, for Key enum, both with same value: 6. I tried to chek every property for KeyEventArgs but I cannot find any difference.

Is is possible know which key the user pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `IsExtendedKey` property that gets set to `true` for the Numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

It's `internal` though, so you'll have to use reflection to get its value:

```
static void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(KeyEventArgs)
            .GetProperty("IsExtendedKey", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (pi != null && (bool)pi.GetValue(e) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Into key was pressed!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter key was pressed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! It is also possible to use it for Home or End keys, but not for operators or Decimal for some reason. I wonder why this property is internal and not public.